# The ClassifierCascade class and CVCascadeClassifier class in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I found that in the OpenCV-2.4.2 sorce code.
There is an implemnt of ClassifierCascade class in `modules\objdetect`. But in apps `\traincascade\`, it implements a CVCascadeClassifier class instead of using the ClassifierCascade class.

**Why the apps not use the class from the library.**
**What's the difference between them.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClassifierCascade class from `modules\objdetect` only includes the detection methods. While the CVCascadeClassifier from `apps \traincascade\` only includes the train metholds.